# Parallel circuit-find value of resistor

Tags: parallel, ohms-law

I have a parallel circuit with 7.5 ohms as total resistance,75 volts, with 2 resistors. R1=10ohms,R2 is unknown. How can I find the value of R2?

Comment: Show your circuit and your work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a homework question with no prior attempts shown, and the OP couldn't even be bothered to provide a schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since \$R_{tot}=\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ it follows from simple algebra that \$R_2=\frac{R_1\cdot R_{tot}}{R_1- R_{tot}}\$. In this case, that means \$R_2=\frac{10\:\Omega\cdot 7.5\:\Omega}{10\:\Omega- 7.5\:\Omega}=30\:\Omega\$. The voltage you mentioned isn't required.

I'd recommend that you commit both parallel resistance formulas to memory, as well. But use some algebra and prove what I said is right. You may need the practice.

Comment: Maybe a bit easier to do 1/R2 = 1/Rt - 1/R1 = 1/7.5-1/10

Comment: You really ought not give direct answers. For all we know you could have just given the OP an answer on a test that he or she was supposed to do on their own

Comment: @DerStrom8 I'm rarely focused on the OP, except as a guide about what they see. It helps other people. I use the questions as a foil of sorts. When I'm in the mood and the questioner doesn't otherwise make a simple answer easy to misdirect. In this case, there's little harm possible I think ... even to the OP. I feel fine about it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yeah, but then you have to do a 1/x again. Anyway, it's very helpful to just memorize the fact that putting them in parallel is a + sign in the denominator and that extracting one or the other uses a - sign. But sure. Any way that works for someone is all good.

Comment: @jonk Re. Spehro's comment, the formula you provide only works when you have two parallel resistors. It may be misleading if the reader has 3 or more resistors in parallel. You cannot just multiply by the third resistance in the numerator and add it in the denominator, you really must use the formula that Spehro provided.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Sure. But I can generalize it as easily as the other. I use Spehro's approach, too. Don't get me wrong. I just think one uses what works for one's self. And I definitely do not believe there is only one approach for every person. Don't want to get into an argument about it, though. You have every right to your opinion on this. But you can't speak for everyone, either. I'll leave it there.

Comment: @jonk fair enough, don't take it personally. Just trying to think of a more general approach that would help more people in the long run, regardless of their problem. Not intending to start an argument =)

Comment: @DerStrom8 No problem. I completely take your points. They are good. I guess I'm just not sure why we've spent so much time on what I wrote in my answer. It's not wrong and it's even appropriate (depending on the person and circumstances.) I'm slightly flummoxed, perhaps, that way too much attention went there. But that's all.